# How to forward/re-direct emails from Outlook Live WebApp account

Tags: email, outlook, email-forwarding, office-365

Our work email accounts were just transferred from our in-house server to Outlook. I want to forward some or all emails arriving in that mailbox to another account. I can't seem to find such an option once I log on to the Outlook account. I'm looking for a re-direction from within Outlook rather than having another account log in thru POP and access my emails. Here is the screenshot once I go to options: (you should be able to zoom in to the picture by viewing it in a separate tab/window)

[image]

Answer (score 12):

That's because you are not using IE. What you are seeing is a non-IE (watered down) version of the app. Therefore, first and foremost, you need to access OWA from Internet Explorer, otherwise you will not see the **Rules** section. Secondly, make sure forwarding is allowed from the Exchange server. Then:

1. Login
2. Click on the **Options** button at the top right of the Outlook Web Access screen
3. Click on the **Rules** link on the left
4. Click the **New rule** button
5. Click **Create a new rule for arriving messages**. A new window opens. On the right underneath *Do the following...* click the link that says **Forward or redirect...** Options appear to "Forward to people or distribution lists" or "Redirect to people or distribution lists." Click the appropriate option for your requirements.
6. Click the "people or distribution lists" link that appears in the left-hand panel. This opens up a new window where you can select who you wish to forward your mail to. Select from your contacts list or enter the desired email address directly in the "To" box at the bottom.
7. Click **OK** when finished.
8. Click **Save** to save your rule and activate your mail forwarding.

(This is from memory, so it might be a little outdated. See [here](http://lis.dickinson.edu/technology/training/Tutorials/Email/outlookweb/outweb_redirect.pdf) a tutorial for OWA 2010.)

Comment: I am on a Mac, so no IE. Safari shows the same UI.

Comment: I also logged in with IE, and it still shows the same UI.

Comment: That's strange. What version?

Comment: @Thanks Alex. I found the answer. I had low resolution settings on in my account.

Comment: Thanks I found instructions similar to this on other sites, but no where mentioned you had to do it in IE. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: @highBandWidth try to use Firefox. It has the full outlook version

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that under Options -> Accessibility -> Low Resolution or Blind settings were on, and the rules options were not being displayed.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am using the Outlook Web App for my University email account, and I happen to be blind. I searched and searched for the forwarding feature--it never occured to me to disable the accessibility settings. Once I did--voila! Thanks again!